# How to change cursor when onDrag is active, ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to use Drag on some elements on my application but the cursor changes when i drag. How do I change the cursor when onDrag is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your dragging event set the cursor by:

```
element.style.custor = 'grap'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `cursor: grab` on the element so its visibile that its also a dragable element